# Updating multiple documents in MongoDB based on value of multiple fields in Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How do I achieve this MongoDB update query in SpringBoot, using mongoTemplate and Aggregation?

```
db.getCollection("dataBank").updateOne({_id: "12345"}, [
    {
      $set: {
        "indexed": true,
        "replicated": true
      }
    }, {
      $set: {
        status: {
          $cond: {
            'if': {
              $eq: [
                {
                  $and: [
                    '$replicated',
                    '$indexed'
                  ]
                },
                true
              ]
            },
            'then': 'COMPLETE',
            'else': "$status"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

On executing the above query in MongoDB, it updates the the indexed and replicated flags of the document with the given ID, and checks that if there are documents in the collection where both the flags are true, it set's their status to "COMPLETE", else it remains as it is, which is "INCOMPLETE".

I have a simple entity and repository.

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import javax.persistence.Id;

@Document(collection = "dataBank")
@Data
public class DataBankEntity {

  @Id private String id;

  private String status;

  private String filePath;

  private String url;

  private String type;

  private String taskName;

  private boolean replicated;

  private boolean indexed;
}
```

And my Repository

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface DataBankRepository extends MongoRepository<DataBankEntity, String> {

}
```